# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'sqlite3.Cursor' and 'int'

Tags: python, database, sqlite, web, discord.py

Tying to get a integer from a sqlite database so I can do a calculation, but I keep having issues when trying to do the math

I understand that grabbing from the database returns a tuple, but I'm not sure how to get just the int out from that tuple, or if there is a way to just return a int

(Thanks for all your help!)

```
xp_update = 'UPDATE xpdata SET xp = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND guild_id = ?'
val = (xp_inc, user_id, guild_id)
cursor.execute(xp_update, val)

lvl_grab = cursor.execute('SELECT level FROM xpdata WHERE(user_id=? AND guild_id=?)', ('user_id', 'guild_id'))
xp_grab = cursor.execute('SELECT xp FROM xpdata WHERE(user_id=? AND guild_id=?)', ('user_id', 'guild_id'))
lvl_start = lvl_grab
lvl_end = int(((xp_grab+xp_inc)//42) ** 0.55)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how you retrieve data from DB, read some https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

```
cursor.execute('SELECT level FROM xpdata WHERE(user_id=? AND guild_id=?)', ('user_id', 'guild_id'))
lvl_grab = cursor.fetchone()[0]

cursor.execute('SELECT xp FROM xpdata WHERE(user_id=? AND guild_id=?)', ('user_id', 'guild_id'))
xp_grab = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

---

But you can retrieve multiple data in one SQL query

```
cursor.execute('SELECT level,xp FROM xpdata WHERE(user_id=? AND guild_id=?)', ('user_id', 'guild_id'))
lvl_grab, xp_grab = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: I was doing this earlier, but I deleted it because I thought it was the wrong way to do it. rip.